# Append a list into a csv file python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I want to append a list into a csv file in python

```
listoflist = [rhyme_cnt[row],gaali_cnt,diversity[row]]
```

This list contains three variables and the code I'm using to write this is

```
with open('C:/Users/Samarth/Desktop/Minor/songlyrics/final.csv',"ab") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output,lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerows(listoflist)
    writer.writerows([])
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: please provide the csv file and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to change the    writerows to writerow and change the open file method from 'ab' to 'a'